# cakedc rating plugin not saving data - cakephp 2.6

Tags: php, mysql, rating, cakedc, cakephp-2.6

I have followed the basic uses of CAKEDC RATING plugin but unable to get it work.
after clicking "Rate" button on the view it does not saving the data in table "ratings".

PostController:

```
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session','Ratings.Ratings');
```

posts/view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Rating->display(array(
    'item' => $post['Post']['id'],
    'type' => 'radio',
    'stars' => 5,
    'value' => 2,
    'createForm' => array(
        'url' => array_merge($this->passedArgs, array(
            'rate' => $post['Post']['id'],
            'redirect' => false
        ))
    )
)); ?>
```

I have debugged the posted data in `RatableBehavior` near line 154:

```
$Model->Rating->create();
debug($data);
exit;
```

output:

```
 array(
        'Rating' => array(
            'foreign_key' => '2',
            'model' => 'Post',
            'user_id' => null,
            'value' => '5'
        )
    )
```

`user_id` is the primary key of the `users` table and `id` of `posts`.

How can I fix it?